# Forming the Differential Equation from the given Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

The solution of a Differential equation is given as:
  $Y(x)= x^nJ_n(x)$
where $J_n(x)$ is Bessel's function(of first kind) of order $n$.
I wanted to find the Corresponding Differential Equation.

Comment: which differential equation? you can contstruct an abritary number out of $Y$

Comment: No. We have to find the corresponding Differential Equation whose solution is of the form given.

Comment: have you tried to rescale bessel's differential equation?

Comment: Rescale? I am not aware of the process.

Comment: Should I try using Laplace Transform?